using React-hook-form need onChange event when passing control to custom component with useController
Based on react-hook-form, I have a custom component like this:
    // inputCont.js
    export const InputCont = ({ name, control, rules, ...others }) => {
        const { field } = useController({ name, control, rules });
        return (        
                <input id={name} {...field} {...others} />
        );
    };

and then I use it in another file like this (I make it simpler):
    // main.js
    const { control, handleSubmit } = useForm();
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit()}>
            <InputCont name="something" type="text"
                        control={control}  autoComplete="off"/>
        </form>
    )

Now I need to have a onChange event handler inside main.js, I know I can add a custom onChange and pass it to the InputCont, but I wonder is this a best practice or there is easier way to use control or other result values of useForm.
